# Should I write tests first (following TDD) for the view layer or only do only manual testing and add snapshot tests when finished?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, tdd

As expected, I normally have difficulties when following TDD (i.e. writing the tests first) with the view layer.

Namely, in order to observe or trigger certain visible changes (layout or styling) I would need to make the view's internals public. This breaks encapsulation and allows for client code do some thing like `myView.label.text = "User"`.

To avoid this, I either add getter methods to `UIView` class:

```
var userName: String{ return label.text }
```

Or do some extensions that are added only to the test framework:

```
extension MyView{

//avoids making a getter just for the sake of testing, while keeping it private and interchangeable
var userName : String{
   return (viewWithTag(someLabelTage) as! UILabel).text
}
```

A different approach is to skip the TDD work flow (i.e. test manually after the feature is done) and add snapshot testing (see https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-snapshot-testing) to the increase coverage and have a safety net when refactoring.

Considering all this, I was wondering if there are any other patterns or approaches, that I can use to be more efficient while keeping my confidence in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not an expert in Swift, but regardless of the language/framework, something tells me you're actually making your task harder.

> *I normally have difficulties when following TDD with the view layer.*

This is expected. The View support to be simple and have no behavior (i.e domain logic) at all. It should be simple user interaction, and binding data to the controls in the view. So you don't need TDD or to be more precise Unit Tests around the View in my opinion. You're not going to get much value out of trying to write Unit tests for the View.

You View can be tested more effectively using a UI test framework, such as Selenium, or your own UI test framework, which tests User interactions. This way you more return in investment (ROI) than attempting to TDD the View layer.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I fully agree domain logic has no business in the views; also some of the difficulties can be due to views being too complicated. I was thinking more of the case where a view other nested views and then there is some data passing behaviour, which I wish to cover. However, due to how the view layer depends on many other things, I may end up skipping writing tests first. I also realised from your response that my question is not very clear, so I edited it in that regard.

Comment: After reading more carefully, I am marking this as accepted due to the emphasis on ROI. I think the focus should be really on getting the best value from the tests and not on writing them for the sake of following certain development discipline (however I much like it).

Comment: I couldn't have said myself better :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much to add to Spock's answer. Tests should be written to help development and maintenance of the code in the future. If they get in the way then either the code is not architected properly or it's code for which the ROI is low.

A pattern that is worth mentioning is the [humble view](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html#HumbleView). There are a few ways to approach it, each with different trade offs, but the gist is to have data structures defining how the view should look like, and then let the view read these data structure and set its properties from them.

This allows you to test that the data structure driving the view is generated properly, without having to test the view itself, because it's nothing but an humble object that reads and sets values.

Comment: Fully agree; just for reference the humble view pattern is covered very well by Uncle Bob's Clean architecture as well (https://www.amazon.com/Clean-Architecture-Craftsmans-Software-Structure/dp/0134494164).

Comment: The problem I normally face with views on iOS is that I normally am dealing with a mutable hierarchy of view objects that needs to be updated (instead of entirely replaced), this requires some work that may lead to errors (missed updates / stale views). An alternative is to replace all views on every new state but this can be either too expensive or compromise any more sophisticated animations. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Definitely, replacing a whole view hierarchy can be costly and provide a bad experience to the user. I glanced at techniques to the functional programming world to update trees of immutable object effectively but never used them, or tried to apply them in the context of view. Software development is about managing a set of tradeoffs, it's totally fine to optimize the view layer for being effective and correct, at the expense of it not being tested.

Comment: Thank you for the great question and conversation @IvanSIvanov. I love talking about these things, I'm convinced that by keeping surfacing friction points between tests and ease of development we'll keep pushing the envelope as a community and make our tools and workflows better and better.